# Balloon game with Corona SDK

Tags: ios, lua, coronasdk

I am totally new to game development for iPhone/iPad.

I have got my code working and all the 10 balloons are floating in the air but I have a few questions:

The balloons should be in the sequence or random order. They move the tendon to the edge and then the player should move back the balloons to the right place with the mouse. How?

What are the right dimensional numbers (x, y) so my balloons are equally displayed and positioned on the screen?

1. My random function keeps popping out more balloons by simple click.
   I would like the user to perform some math operations, for instance add two random balloons and display the right answer on the screen so the result can move back to the right edge of balloon placement. how to code this? How can I use 2 different level of difficulties? (L1, L2)
2. How to make my balloons to move to the different edges on the screen?
3. How can a user move back the balloons with mouse to the right places?
4. How can I tie my balloons to a rope (horizontally)? so the user can make a choice.
5. My background image is about 3MB original(1024 x 768) to match well with iPad resolution, can I change the size without affecting the display in iPad?
6. I feel like the local balloon1, 2, 3, is repeated too much, and same goes to moveBalloon and applyLinear. Is there a way of shortening them? or is it normal since there are 10 balloons?
7. I have added sound to the first balloon by simple click, should duplicate the same function for the rest of the 9 balloons (another mess)? I will use the same sound to all.

Your feedback is much appreciated.

Comment: I see you tried to add code but couldn't.  Have you tried selecting the code and pressing the "{}" button?

Answer (score 0):

If you want multiple balloons, it would be MUCH MUCH easier to use a table. You can have as many baloons as you want with very little effort.

```
 Balloons = {} -- track all baloons
 Function addBalloon(x,y,xVel,yVel)
     Tab = {x = x, y = y, vel = {x = xVel, y = yVel}}
     Table.insert(balloons,tab)
 End
 Function moveAllBalloons()
     For_,i in pairs(balloons) do
         i.x = i.x + i.vel.x
         i.y = i.y + i.vel.y      
     End
 End
  Function isPlaying
   For _,i in pairs(balloons)
     If --[[mouse.x]] <= i.x - (balloon.width/2) and --[[other parameters here]] then
         PlaySound
     End
  End
  End
```

for different difficulties, you can do something like

```
     if L1 then
        Num1 = math.random(3,15)
        Num2 = math.random(3,15
        OpFind = math.random(3)
        If opfind == 1 then
            Operation = "+"
        Elseif opfind == 2 then
            Operation = "-"
         Elseif opfind ==3 then
            Operation = "*"
        End
    ElseIf L2 then 
        num1 = math.random(7,50)
        Num2 = math.random(7,50)
        OpFind = math.random(4)
        If opfind == 1 then
            Operation = "^"
        Elseif opfind == 2 then
            Operation = "%"
         Elseif opfind ==3 then
            Operation = "*"
         Elseif opfind == 4 then
             Operation == "/"
        End
     End
```